# lsqnonlin matlab stops execution

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I am using the Matlab function `lsqnonlin` for estimating a vector of 5 values.
Before calling `lsqnonlin`, I am making a rough estimation of the 3 parameters, and afterwards the `lsqnonlin` is being initialised using these three parameters (the other two are constant)

In some cases, the following error stops the execution:

> Error using eig
>   Input to EIG must not contain NaN or Inf.
>
> Error in trust (line 30)
>   [V,D] = eig(H);
>
> Error in trdog (line 110)
>   [st,qpval,po,fcnt,lambda] = trust(rhs,MM,delta);
>
> Error in snls (line 320)
>   [sx,snod,qp,posdef,pcgit,Z] = trdog(x,g,A,D,delta,dv,...
>
> Error in lsqncommon (line 150)    [xC,FVAL,LAMBDA,JACOB,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,msgData]=...
>
> Error in lsqnonlin (line 237)[xCurrent,Resnorm,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,JACOB] = ...

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The error is quite specific about the problem.  Could you post the system you are solving since that may shed some light on why the trust region algorithm is generating NaNs/Infs?

Comment: I know two vectors (A,B) of length n and i am trying to find the third (X of length n) which is a function of 5 parameters (to be estimated). These three vectors are related with convolution A=conv[B,X(estimation vector)]

Comment: So your function is `@(params) A - conv(B,X(params))`?  Then it may be a lower/upper bound problem on the value of parameters.  Have you tried limiting their range with the `lb` and `ub` options of [`lsqnonlin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html)?

Comment: Yes these are limited both ways. I am solving this problem for every pixel of an image (uncorrelated each time) and I suppose that in some pixels the data are very noisy. If i found a way to bypass these "problematic" pixels (terminate the optimisation problem in that pixel and proceed to the next - without having results of the estimation in that pixel) it would be also helpfull.

Comment: Then the only way I can see the error being thrown is if those problem pixels are, for some reason, `NaN` or `Inf` or some other nonsensical value.  I'd think setting those pixels to `0` or some benign value is the best way to fix the problem.

Comment: The range of values of all the pixels is from zero to a finite number.